# ¿Cómo ejecutar Doofinder sin input text? - Doofinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

Estoy intentando mostrar el form de Doofinder pero sin tener un input text.
He intentado crear el input y hacer un trigger para poder llamarlo cuando yo quiera pero sin éxito :(

HTML:

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>var doofinder_script = '//cdn.doofinder.com/media/js/doofinder-fullscreen.latest.min.js';
                (function (d, t) {
                    var f = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
                    f.async = 1;
                    f.src = ('https:' == location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + doofinder_script;
                    f.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(f, s)
                }(document, 'script')
                        );
                var dfFullscreenLayers = [{
                        "toggleInput": "#opendoofinder",
                        "zone": "XXXX",
                        "hashid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        "display": {
                            "lang": "es"
                        }
                    }];
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="opendoofinder" style="display: none;"/>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '.toggle_search_opened, .menu_hamb_left .closehamb .searchbox', function (e) {
                $('#opendoofinder').focus();
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambiando el `input` por un `<a>`

```
<a id="opendoofinder" style="display: none;"></a>
```

Resuelta por el administrador de Doofinder vía email